# Appending text to textview

Tags: android, kotlin, button, textview

There's a button with the following onClick event:

```
fun add(view: View) {
    txt.append((view as Button).text)
}
```

But I get an error on using `+=` operator.

```
fun add(view: View) {
    txt.text += (view as Button).text   //error
}
```

What's wrong with the second code??

Comment: Just use the = operator. If you need to add the text, I would go with concatenation / interpolation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-idioms-strings.html).

Comment: What is the type of txt?  If it's a String, that's a problem.  view.text returns a CharSequence.  The append function takes a CharSequence, so it works.  But += requires a String, not just a CharSequence.  Remember that a String is a CharSequence, but not all CharSequences are Strings.  It could also be solved with txt.text += (view as Button).text .toString()

Comment: Using `toString()` doesn't work for me :(
@GabeSechan

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution with string interpolation:

```
private fun add(view: View) {
    txt.text = "${txt.text} ${(view as Button).text}"
}
```

This is the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-idioms-strings.html).

Give it a read and let me know if this doesn't solve your problem, happy coding!

***EDIT***

Regarding your question: i think [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-kotlin-does-not-support-overloading-of-the-assignment-operator/19416) is the only "valid" answer I found looking around.

Comment: I'm curious to know why `+=` doesn't work here

Comment: Can't find anything better than the link above, if someone knows exactly why this happens it would be great to know